# VAT for Sole Trader in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-law

I run a website, by which we develope website extensions. Last year, I thought I'd release a commercial extension simply to contribute towards the hosting and domain expenses.

Before doing so, I registered as a Sole Trader.

According to the GOV.UK website, **You must register for VAT if your business turnover is over £82,000.**

Now seeing as my site only turns over a couple of hundred pounds every few months, am I still required to notify HMRC of my revenue and pay VAT on it?

I only ask as I received a letter from HMRC saying I was required to pay £75.

Comment: Is it clear that the fee requested by HMRC is a VAT, or could it be some other tax or fee?  E.g., maybe just a registration fee?

Comment: @feetwet - I'm sure that it was VAT. I assume the best thing to do would be to contact HMRC